# Why I am getting type error undefined from my jquery from my php json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I don't know what is wrong is am I just missing something, all my expected data is successfully receive based on firebug' console tab the problem is displaying the data.

Here's my jquery code:

```
success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';
            if(typeof data === "object"){
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    toAppend += '<tr><td colspan="2">'+data[i]['main-asin'][0]+'</td></tr>';
                    toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data[i]['sub-asin'][0]+'</td><td></td></tr>';
                }
                $('.data-results').append(toAppend);
            }
        }
```

Here's my php code:

```
    foreach($xml->Items->Item as $item){
    $items_from_amazon[] = array('main-asin'=>$item->ASIN);
    foreach($xml->Items->Item->Variations->Item as $item){
        $items_from_amazon[] = array('sub-asin'=>$item->ASIN);
    }
}

echo json_encode($items_from_amazon); //return amazon products
```

And here's the result from my firebug:
[image]

Comment: Erm... because `data[0]['sub-asin']` IS `undefined`? )

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you use `$.each` to iterate over the JSON, makes life a lot easier in that case.

Comment: Just like in the example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2):

Each element of `$items_from_amazon` array is an associative array with a *single* key, that is either `main-asin` or `sub-asin`. So the first element of `data` array will have `main-asin` property set, but not `sub-asin`; all the others will have only `sub-asin`, but no `main-asin`.

The one way to fix it is to update your code like that:

```
toAppend += '<tr><td colspan="2">'+data[0]['main-asin'][0]+'</td></tr>';
for(var i = 1; i<data.length; i++){
  toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data[i]['sub-asin'][0]+'</td><td></td></tr>';
}
```

... but perhaps it's better to alter the structure of BOTH response AND processing code:

```
PHP:

foreach($xml->Items->Item as $item){
  $new_item_from_amazon = array(
    'main-asin' => $item->ASIN,
    'sub-asin'  => array(),
  ); 
  foreach($xml->Items->Item->Variations->Item as $item) {
    $new_item_from_amazon['sub_asin'][] = $item->ASIN;
  }
  $items_from_amazon[] = $new_item_from_amazon;
}

JS:

toAppend += '<tr><td colspan="2">'+data['main-asin']+'</td></tr>';
for (var i = 0, l = data['sub-asin'].length; i < l; i++){
  toAppend += '<tr><td>'+data['sub-asin'][i]+'</td><td></td></tr>';
}
```

I've assigned an empty array as `sub-asin` value here to avoid additional checking `data['sub-asin']` in JS.